# Is it possible to use Cygwin on Windows to develop Node.js apps with Yarn?

Tags: node.js, npm, yarnpkg

I would like to get started with, and use yarn.

I am using cygwin on windows, I launch and type:

```
$yarn init
```

and I get:

```
$ yarn init
yarn init v1.12.3
error An unexpected error occurred: "Can't answer a question unless a user TTY".
info If you think this is a bug, please open a bug report with the information provided in "C:\\home\\code\\repos\\pwa\\yarn-error.log".
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/init for documentation about this command.
```

---

### What does means: "Can't answer a question unless a user TTY"?

Am I prevented from using a bash shell provided by cygwin with yarn?  I could not find any document telling me what terminal/shell I should download and use.

I need to be productive using my bash shell with scripts, aliases, command line completion, and have access to a full range of gnu commands for scripting and so therefore a DOS command prompt or powershell is not an option.

Comment: If you're using a newer version of Windows 10, you can use the [builtin Unix kernel](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/wsl-2-is-now-available-in-windows-insiders/).

Answer (score 0):

Yes!

**TL;DR:** Update to the latest yarn version. Skip to the end to see how to get the latest version. It is NOT as simple as it sounds.

I believe it could be done in yarn 1.x if you modify the `/c/Program Files/nodejs/yarn` file to work correctly with cygwin. I don't get why that script was written the way it was, but I can see why it wouldn't work on the cygwin terminal: for some paths, it converts them to windows paths, then appends linux paths to the end of it. I *bet* if you modify that to use linux (i.e., cygwin) paths, yarn 1.x will run correctly.

But, this is not a great answer because it's all hypothetical. Luckily, there's an even simpler solution that isn't hypothetical: upgrade to the latest `yarn`. Once I did this, cygwin worked correctly. They probably fixed a bug in the older versions.

You may be saying to yourself, "I just ran `npm install yarn` so I already have the latest version." That doesn't mean you have the latest yarn. For some reason, that installs the latest version of **1.x**. The latest version of yarn is 3.x.

Also, to go from 1.x to latest, you need to run some ad-hoc commands -- as opposed to `npm install`ing something else.

Here is [the guide to go from yarn 1.x to latest](https://yarnpkg.com/getting-started/migration#why-should-you-migrate):

1. Run `npm install -g yarn` to update the global yarn version to latest v1
2. Go into your project directory
3. Run `yarn set version berry` to enable v2
4. If you used .npmrc or .yarnrc, you'll need to turn them into the new format
5. Add nodeLinker: node-modules in your .yarnrc.yml file

   *I don't know what step 4 means. But my current .yarnrc looks like this:*

   ```
   yarnPath: ".yarn/releases/yarn-berry.cjs"
   nodeLinker: node-modules
   ```
6. Commit the changes so far (yarn-X.Y.Z.js, .yarnrc.yml, ...)
7. Run `yarn install` to migrate the lockfile
8. Use `yarn` the way you normally would.